# passport.js failed to store session during live production server

Tags: node.js, session, serialization, passport.js, middleware

When I ran the server **locally** at port `8080`, it worked normally at authenticating and serializing data. But the time I ran my code on **live production**, yea it normally authenticate but it doesn't store any data to session!

I wonder what middleware supposed to be setup for this matter?

Answer (score 1):

According to [`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session) middleware documentation:

> The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is
>   purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak
>   memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process,
>   and is meant for debugging and developing.
>
> For a list of stores, see [compatible session stores](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores).

Two most popular one for production environments are:

- [connect-mongo](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo)
- [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis)